# Is there a name for a metric space being "arbitrarily well covered by a specific collection of subsets"?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

This is a question about existence of terminology.

Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then, I say that $(X,\mathcal{F})$ has "property (*)" if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $F\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $\cup_{x\in F}B_X(x,\epsilon)=X$, where $B_X(x,\epsilon)$ is the ball in $X$ with center $x$ and radius $\epsilon$.

In other words, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $F\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $F$ is an $\epsilon$-cover of $X$.

> Is there a name for "property (*)"?

**Note**: If $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of finite subsets of $X$, then $(X,\mathcal{F})$ has property (*) if and only if $X$ is totally bounded.